# React: only map when props exists

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to do conditional rendering in React (only maps and renders when props exist).

```
render() {
    if (this.props.res) {
      return(
        <div>{this.props.res.map(item => <li key={item.id}>{item.subreddit}</li>}</div>
      )
    } else {
      return null
    }
  }
```

But I have this error:

```
Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","
```

Why is that, and how can I fix it? Or in another way, is there a better way to achieve my purpose?

Comment: "*`li` must be contained in a parent element: an ordered list `<ol>`, an unordered list `<ul>` or a menu `<menu>`*" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the issues I see:

- `map` is missing the closing parenthesis
- check the array length (an empty array will return `true` otherwise)
- list items should be wrapped with an appropriate tag, such as `<ul/>`

---

```
render() {
    const { res } = this.props;
    return !res.length ? null : (
        <ul>{res.map(item => <li key={item.id}>{item.subreddit}</li>)}</ul>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is syntax error, `map(...)` doesn't have closing parenthesis.

It should be:

```
<div>{this.props.res.map(item => <li key={item.id}>{item.subreddit}</li>)}</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

there was a brace missing in the end of the map.

```
render() {

  return (
    <div>
      {
      this.props.res && this.props.res.map(item => (
        <li key={item.id}>{item.subreddit}</li>
      ))
     }
    </div>
  );
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
render() {
    if (this.props.res) {
      return (
        <div>
          {this.props.res.map(item => (
            <li key={item.id}>{item.subreddit}</li>
          ))}
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```